# Move Files having No Extension

Tags: linux, bash, unix, bash-scripting

I have 5 files in a directory

```
log.txt
abc.pdf
def.ppt
1CC
1DD
```

Now I want to Move files having no extension i.e 1CC and 1DD to a another directory i.e tree.

whenever i am manually using command it will work.

```
command : 
shopt -s extglob
mv !(*.*) tree
```

but in a bash script it shows the error
script :

```
#/bin/bash
mkdir tree
shopt -s extglob
mv !(*.*) tree/
```

and saved as stuct.sh
after running it

it shows the following error:

```
struc.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('
struc.sh: line 11: `mv !(*.*) tree/'
```

I have No idea why this is happening.
Please provide solution for the same. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're using [special characters](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html) in your script. You'll have to escape them.

You can better use `find` for this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "*.*" -exec mv -t ./tree/ {} \+
```

This command will:

- `find` search
- `.` in the current directory
- `-maxdepth 1` with a depth of 1 (so no subdirectories)
- `type -f` only files
- `! -name "*.*"` where the filename does not match `*.*`
- `-exec mv -t ./tree/ {} \+` execute the `mv` command, the `-t` argument specifies the target directory (`tree` in the current directory (`.`)) and appends (`\+`) the filename (`{}`) to it.

This will work in your bash script and it does not try to move directories or your own `tree` directory to itself (which your `mv` command will try).